# Django-Verify-Email 2.0.3 is not defined even after i installed it

Tags: python, django, django-settings

im new to django and im trying to verify users email with Django-Verify-Email 2.0.3. As the documentation says i installed the package and did the same steps as they say but i get this error

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'verify_email'**

i checked pip and it's already installed what is the problem

is there any steps i should do first like create new app of name verify_email or something?

i tryed to reinstall the package but same problem still appear

Answer (score 0):

Pip can be a bit frustrating at times, especially if you've got multiple versions of python installed on your machine. When I run into this problem, what I typically do is check that pip has it installed but speciically *within the instance I'm running*. A quick way to do this is by running pip list *within the instance!* Open up an instance of python and run something akin to:

```
import os
print(os.system("pip list"))
```

If the module *still* appears in that list but refuses to be found when importing, then something else has gone awry - potentially the name used when pip installing is not the same that is used when importing in python, but that would be a question for the documentation.

If it does not appear in the list, then pip is installing to the wrong version of python! what you might need to do in this case is reassign which python instance is being considered default in your environmental paths. Open up an instance of your python and run:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

and it'll show you where your python instance says it's running the .exe from, and  you'll need to set the folder containing that .exe in your environmental variables as your global path to python. More information on how to do that can be found here: [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem with creating a virtual environment and it worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).